# Password Decryption in Python using cryptograpy

Tags: python, flask

Try to decrypt the password stored in my MongoDB, but it shows a **cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken**
here is my code...

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

sec_key = b"My_message"  # Password Encode Secret Key Before Password Encrypt
salt = os.urandom(32)
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32, salt=salt, iterations=100000,
            backend=default_backend()
        )
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(sec_key))
f = Fernet(key)

password = "x7zBCHki"
token = f.encrypt(bytes(password, encoding='utf-8'))
print("Token:", token)
print(type(token))
tek = token.decode()
```

Using this code I stored my Encrypted password into my **MongoDB** and know try to decrypt that password but shows an Invalid Tokenization.
here is my encrypted key...

---

password = "**x7zBCHki**"
Encrypted = 
gAAAAABeDvAiNwUIZ9OyT_Ze-eSBdtVHWNmDbq_liREZtpNiPBlKHXIXmjeRe2kHQwHmgBs8tvFqtSVRUJSKxig-mV6qMe78DA==

---

This Encrypted code is in string format

---

- **Decryption Code**

---

```
dec = f.decrypt(bytes(tek, encoding='utf-8')).decode()
print("Decode :",dec)
print(type(dec))

if dec == password:
    print("Match")
else:
    print("Not Match")
```

---

**ERROR Message:**

---

```
Admin@DESKTOP-48C6LC5 MINGW64 /p/WSSP/Blockchain/yourapplication (master)
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\WSSP\Blockchain\blockchain\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 104, in _verify_signature
    h.verify(data[-32:])
  File "P:\WSSP\Blockchain\blockchain\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py", line 66, in verify
    ctx.verify(signature)
  File "P:\WSSP\Blockchain\blockchain\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py", line 74, in verify
    raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    dec = f.decrypt(bytes(tek, encoding='utf-8')).decode()
  File "P:\WSSP\Blockchain\blockchain\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, ttl)
  File "P:\WSSP\Blockchain\blockchain\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 117, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "P:\WSSP\Blockchain\blockchain\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 106, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Help me to solve this Decryption method
**NOTE:** When I use simple message and encrypt and then decrypt it run smoothly but when I fetched from MongoDB and then decrypted it, then it shows such an error.

Comment: Your example code is working for me. Did you use the same `salt`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I completely understand your question.

You say you can encrypt and decrypt a password with some code.

Now if you store the encrypted password in MongoDB and try to decrypt it it doesn't work?

Can you show the shortest code snipped showing, that you can encrypt and decrypt a password?

Can you also show the shortest code snippet showing, that you cannot encrypt and decrypt a password if storing and retrieving with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you used different salts for encryption and decryption.
Since you use a fixed secret key, you can also use some fixed salt:

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

SECRET_KEY = b"My_message"  # Password Encode Secret Key Before Password Encrypt
SALT = b"sAlT"*8

def get_fenec():
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32, salt=SALT, iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(SECRET_KEY))
    return Fernet(key)

def encrypt_password(password):
    f = get_fenec()
    token = f.encrypt(bytes(password, encoding='utf-8'))
    return token.decode()

def decrypt_password(tek):
    f = get_fenec()
    return f.decrypt(bytes(tek, encoding='utf-8')).decode()

password = "x7zBCHki"
tek = encrypt_password(password)

tek = 'gAAAAABeDyduJrAmHBtfCPMAKWwBPYFAFJhCAtPf3EerNt9OVfZIADe_9Pap-DiGK8VF6EQ_w62hUIeqHP9kiHf5u58blIL6qQ=='
decrypted_password = decrypt_password(tek)
```

But, since everybody can read the secret key in your code, you can just use the fenec key directly:

```
KEY = b'gcPZx4_UiXtw8Zl0dSCJnY02FKejaMQ-8a40RbLnO0M='

def get_fenec():
    return Fernet(KEY)
```